# Algorithm development and optimization

Tags: algorithm

I have this problem:
You need to develop a meal regime based on the data entered by the user. We have a database with the meals and their prices (meals also have a mark whether they are breakfast, cause on breakfast we eat smth different from lunch and dinner most often). The input receives the amount of money (Currency is not important) and the number of days. At the output, we must get a meal regime for a given number of days. Conditions:

1. Final price does not differ from the given one by more than 3%.
2. meals mustn't repeat more than once every 5 days.

I found this not effective solution: We are looking for an average price per day = amount of money / number of days. Then, until we reach the given number of days, we iterate throught each breakfast, then lunch and dinner (3 for loops, 2 are nested) and if price is not too different, then we end the search and add this day to the result list. So the design now looks like this:

```
while(daysCounter < days){
    for(){
        for(){
            for(){

            }
        }
```

It looks scary, although there is not a lot of data (number of meals is about 150). There are thoughts that it is possible to find a more effective solution. Also i think about dynamic programming, but so far there are no ideas how to implement it.

Comment: What data is entered by the user?

Comment: User entering number of days and money

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic programming won't work because a necessary part of your state is the meals from the last 5 days.  And the number of possibilities for that are astronomical.

However it is likely that there are many solutions, not just a few.  And that it is easy to find a working solution by being greedy.  Also that an existing solution can be improved fairly easily.

So I'd solve it like this.  Replace days with an array of meals.  Take the total you want to spend.  Divide it up among your meals, in proportion to the median price of the options for that meal. (Breakfast is generally cheaper than dinner.) And now add up that per meal cost to get running totals.

And now for each meal choose the meal you have not had in the last 5 days that brings the running total of what has been spent as close as possible to the ideal total.  Choose all of your meals, one at a time.

This is the greedy approach.  Normally, but not always, it will come fairly close to the target.

And now, to a maximum of `n` tries or until you have the target within 3%, pick a random meal, consider all options that are not eaten within the last or next 5 days, and randomly pick one (if any such options exist) that brings the overall amount spent closer to the target.

(For a meal plan that is likely to vary more over a long period, I'd suggest trying simulated annealing.  That will produce more interesting results, but it will also take longer.)